# String interpolation in AJAX call data parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

I have a `locale` variable that can be `en`, `fr`, or `es`.
I have to send an AJAX request, with the locale as the key of the `data` parameter.

```
let locale = "en";
let name = "example";
$.ajax({
  url: "/path",
  method: "PUT",
  data: {characteristic: {`${locale}`: name}},
  success: function(){},
  error: function(){}
})
```

I tried to use ES6's string interpolation, but it raises a syntax error.
How can I do this ?

I'd like to get, depending on the locale:

```
{en: "example"}
{fr: "example"}
{es: "example"}
```

Comment: Why do you need _ES6's string interpolation_?

Comment: I also tried string concatenation, didn't seem to work either. I'm open to any solution though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can use [computed property names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames):

```
{ [locale]: name } 

// if local is "en" the above will equal { "en": name }
```

In general, to use a computed property name you put the value to be computed in square brackets, like so:

```
{ [1 + 2]: 'three' } // is equal to { '3': 'three' }
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about computed properties. Thanks for the additional example.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
[`${locale}`]: name
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from [here](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals), you need an array-like brackets to define dynamic property names:

```
{
  characteristic: {
    [locale]: name
  }
}
```